# In Fusion, how can I add a different coloured border around a shape?

Tags: motion-graphics, blackmagic, fusion, shape

I want to create a shape that has a border that is different from the shape's fill.
Here is an example of what I want to achieve in the end:

[image: ellipse example]

Please note that the image in the background is only an example to better demonstrate the transparency of the ellipse and its border. Also yes in this case it is not different colours, but I figure if I can do different colours, different opacities will be basically the same.

Now here is where I thought I was smart:

[image: fusion nodes]

I have the same shape node feeding into a merge node and an outline node respectively, the latter of which also feeding into the merge node. I thought the outline node would allow me to pick a colour but sadly it doesnt. Now my next idea was to add some different node after the outline node that allows me to change the colour of the outline, however I am unable to find any ...

My current output is just an ellipse because the outline has the same colour (and in this case opacity) as the ellipse ...

[image: fusion output]